# Custom Components problem in android

Tags: android, components

I am trying to draw custom shapes in my Android application. I used this http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/ example and I can get it working with my application if the only thing that I have is this component. However, I need to use custom shapes AND 2 TextViews and 2 Buttons. Whenever I try to create this component within my application with Buttons and TextViews the App fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/back" android:layout_width="160sp"
                android:textSize="20sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Previous" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_width="160sp"
                android:textSize="20sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextSwitcher android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextSwitcher android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <com.android.example.DemoView android:id="@+id/demoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/info" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About this App" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thats my Layout XML file, I kinda suspect that it is the problem. What could be causing the error?

Here is the LogCar error log.

> 03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.project.realtimedata/android.project.realtimedata.ViewData}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.project.realtimedata.ViewData.onCreate(ViewData.java:77)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   03-21 19:34:08.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608):     ... 11 more

Comment: paste the logcat after the app crashes.

Comment: add the logcat output, it's hard to guess without that

Comment: so you have a fatal exception ... caused by a `NullPointerException` thrown at line 77 of your `ViewData.java`. Could you post your `onCreate()` method and tell us which one is line 77?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the DemoView is giving you issues.  Try removing it and go from there.  Sorry this is not a full answer.